# How to upload entire FOLDERS to Azure Website using scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, static-site, kudu

I'm trying to use Azure Website to create a simple static site. Unfortunately, when I try the Kudu console,(https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole
) I'm only allowed to drag n' drop a file at a time AND I have to use IE/Edge. I don't want to recreate the entire folder structure one file at a time. I'd also like to use any browser.

What is the best method here? Ideally Azure Websites would connect to GitHub, but I'm just trying to slap up something quick at this point.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

for completeness, you can also drag-n-drop **the folder**
[image]
whereas for zip files, you need to drop it in a specific section for auto extract
[image]
but using zip is recommended, it is faster

Answer (score 0):

You can make a .zip file and drag-n-drop that into the right-side of the folder listing.

[image: Drag and dropping a zip file to the Kudu debug console]

It will be automatically extracted.

Comment: really? autoextract? hrm